# How do I stop the Debugpy server and detach the debugger?

Tags: visual-studio-code, blender, remote-debugging, vscode-debugger, debugpy

I am using Debugpy to run a debug server from the Blender Python scripting environment, and I have successfully attached and debugged with VS Code. However, I cannot figure out a way to break the connection and shut down the debug server from within Blender where I called it.

I can disconnect from the VS Code side by pressing the disconnect button. I would like to add an operator in Blender that will allow me to kill the connection from there though.

Nominally, it would look something like `debugpy.disconnect`, but that doesn't seem to be an option in the [Debugpy API documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/wiki/API-Reference). How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and found that this worked:

`import pydevd
pydevd.stoptrace()`

It's a shame its not accessible via the public api.